# Extracting raw message in Gmail apps-script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, mime, gmail-addons

In my Gmail-addon, I want to be able to read the raw (MIME) message of the current email.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the message ID of the current message using `e.messageMetadata.messageId` at `function buildAddOn(e){}`. I cannot uderstand about `raw (MIME) message` in your question. So I propose 2 patterns.

- If you want the raw data of `Byte[]`, you can retrieve it from message ID using `Gmail.Users.Messages.get()` of Advanced Google Services as follows.

  - `Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", messageId, {format: "RAW"}).raw`
  - If you use this, please enable Gmail App at Advanced Google Services and API console.
- If you want the raw data of `String`, you can retrieve it from message ID using `GmailApp.getMessageById()` as follows.

  - `GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).getRawContent()`

#### Note :

- If you use this, please set `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://mail.google.com/"` to the scopes.

  - If other scopes are required to be added, please also add them.

#### References :

- [Gmail Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/quickstart)
- [Gmail.Users.Messages.get()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)
- [getMessageById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getMessageById(String))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.